# serializable snapshot isolation and select for update

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, isolation-level

I just have read [serializable snapshot isolation](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI) in PostgresQL and understood from it that using this isolation level DB by itself preventing so called `writing skew`.

The question: is it still meaningful for DB when I mark reads with `FOR UPDATE` sql postfix when it's going to be update after read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is meaningful. By using `FOR UPDATE`, you can prevent some serialization errors from happening (because you are explicitly serializing operations), which will improve performance if conflicts are frequent.